# Books for fractals in physics - question undelete

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions, resource-recommendation

I recently found this question

> [Fractals in physics. Suggest book titles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12784/fractals-in-physics-suggest-book-titles)

which is currently deleted ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMCTR.png)). I'm not sure it's a great question but it [seems to matter to some people](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/16686/fractals-in-physics-suggest-book-titles). When it was closed it was off-topic by the then-current `books` policy, but it is now a fixable question. I'm not sure why it was deleted - is there something I'm missing?

Ideally, this question should be undeleted, have the books banner added, and have its answers collected into the usual CW collection.

Comment: Although you included a screenshot I un-deleted the post for the sake of this meta discussion.

Comment: Usually with such questions it's a good idea to add your own wiki answer that consolidates the non-descriptive answers, and then flag for bookification.

Comment: Why in the world do moderators unilaterally delete such upvoted questions with useful upvoted answers  in the first place, as it can be seen when looking at the edit history ...?

Comment: @Manish that works for non-deleted posts .

Comment: @Dilaton I'm not really sure such a question helps very much; there are several different moderators who handle many different posts. Why not ask why this one was deleted, and work to fix it? It's not a great question to begin with, it's worth fixing but not really worth getting worked up about.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I meant now :)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty probably because it wasn't allowed according to the policies at that time (policies which have changed now. The rbook recommendation policy has gone from being permissive in the early days, to very restrictive after SE decided that they wanted to cut down on poll-ish questions being conducted, to permissive again when we created the new book rec policy on meta.